# Query with conditions on dictionary's keys

Tags: sql, postgresql, dictionary, cardinality-estimation

In a database I have a column (B) that has dictionaries in each element.

Eg. (from an element of the column B):

{
"table": 12,
"chair": 34,
"cat": 65,
}

I want to calculate its cardinality using hll.
In a query:

```
select hll(A, B, C) as card 
from ...
where A = 12
```

I would like to exclude any cases where 'table is in the column B (I want to exclude the key-value pairs where 'table' is a key).
How to do it (is it possible)?

I have tried to add, in the where clauses,:

```
and B:key not ilike '%table%'
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?`(hll and ilike are unfamiliar to me.)

Comment: Postgres. hll is just similar to count(distinct .. )